# SPFx TextField component setState

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, modern-experience, react

New to SPFx and React.

I'm trying the set the state of a TextField when I enter data into the react component and eventually use a button to drop it into a list.  This is bringing information into the web part from a list using REST and that part actually works but is omitted.  I was trying to create the code to set the state on the TextFields when I went down the rabbit hole on this.

The `handleChange` event syntax is not right and I am unable to figure it out.  Would like to be able to set the state on the `MyItems.Title` to what is in the TextField  so I can eventually save it.

I got this code from a course I'm taking but this part I've been unable to get to work.

```
export default class CrudWithReact extends React.Component<ITaWebpartProps, IMyState> {
  
  private _selection: Selection;
  private _onItemsSelectionChanged = () => {
    
    this.setState({
      MyListItem: (this._selection.getSelection()[0] as IMyListItem)
    });
  }
  public constructor(props: ITaWebpartProps, state:IMyState) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      status: "",
      MyListItems: [],
      MyListItem: {
        Id:0,
        Title: "test",
        lastname:""
      }
      
    };  
   
    this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);

    this._selection = new Selection({
      onSelectionChanged: this._onItemsSelectionChanged,
    }); 
  }

   public handleChange=(e)=>{
        this.setstate({this.state.MyListItem:e.target.value});
    }public render(): React.ReactElement<ITaWebpartProps> 

{
  
    const dropdownRef = React.createRef<IDropdown>();

    return (
      <div className={ styles.taWebpart='' }>
        

          <TextField                  
                  label="FirstName(actually Title)"
                  required={ true } 
                  readOnly={false}
                  defaultValue={(this.state.MyListItem.Title)}
                 //value={this.state.MyListItem.Title}
                  styles={textFieldStyles}
                 onChange={this.handleChange}
                  name="title"
                />
                <TextField                  
                  label="LastName"
                  required={ true } 
                  defaultValue={(this.state.MyListItem.lastname)}
                 
                  /* onChange={this.handleChange} */
                  name='lastname'
                  />
                
              <p className={styles.title}>
                   <PrimaryButton
                    text='Add'      
                    title='Add'              
                    onClick={this.btnAdd_click}
                  />

                  <PrimaryButton
                    text='Update'                    
                    onClick={this.btnUpdate_click}
                  />

                  <PrimaryButton
                    text='Delete'                    
                    onClick={this.btnDelete_click}
                  />

                <PrimaryButton
                  text='My new button'
                  onClick={this.testbutton_click}
                />
                </p> 


                <div id="divStatus">
                  {this.state.status}
                </div>

                <div>
                <DetailsList
                      items={ this.state.MyListItems}
                      columns={ _mylistitemscols }
                      setKey='Id'
                      checkboxVisibility={ CheckboxVisibility.onHover}
                      selectionMode={ SelectionMode.single}
                      layoutMode={ DetailsListLayoutMode.fixedColumns }
                      compact={ true }
                      selection={this._selection}                                         
                  />
                  </div>  
      </div>
    );


  }
}
```

The Interface:

```
import { IMyListItem } from "./IMyListItem";

export interface IMyState {
    status: string;
    MyListItems: IMyListItem[];
    MyListItem: IMyListItem;
    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public handleChange = (e) => {
    let myListItem = {...this.state.MyListItem};
    myListItem.Title = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ MyListItem: myListItem });
}
```

**Reference**: [How to update nested state properties in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-nested-state-properties-in-react)